# error in parsing JSON value

Tags: json, jq

Somehow, I'm not able to parse values for the below JSON.

> not able to get this qlog.QBOL-QUERY-SCHEMA value(getting string invalid 
>   error)

I was looking for something output like this:

```
id:104909913,QBOL-QUERY-SCHEMA:/tmp/2017-10-31/5031/104909913.dir/000
```

JSON file:

```
{
  "id":104909913,
  "path":"/tmp/2017-10-31/5031/104909913",
  "status":"done",
  "created_at":"2017-10-31T05:03:19Z",
  "updated_at":"2017-10-31T05:10:24Z",
  "command_type":"HiveCommand",
  "progress":100,
  "qbol_session_id":6527670,
  "qlog":"{\"QBOL-QUERY-SCHEMA\":{\"/tmp/2017-10-31/5031/104909913.dir/000\":[{\"ColumnType\":\"string\",\"ColumnName\":\"ts_date\"},{\"ColumnType\":\"bigint\",\"ColumnName\":\"testing_requests\"},{\"ColumnType\":\"bigint\",\"ColumnName\":\"testings_placed\"}]},\"EXECUTION_ENGINE\":\"mr\",\"QBOL-S3N-BYTES-READ\":1258754351,\"QBOL-S3N-BYTES-WRITTEN\":224,\"HIVE_VERSION\":\"0.13\"}",
  "resolved_macros":null,
  "pid":27212,
  "template":"generic",
  "submit_time":1509426199,
  "start_time":1509426202,
  "end_time":1509426624,
  "can_notify":false,
  "num_result_dir":1,
  "pool":null,
  "timeout":null,
  "name":null,
  "command_source":"API",
  "account_id":5031,
  "saved_query_mutable_id":null,
  "user_id":12146,
  "label":"default",
  "meta_data":{
    "results_resource":"commands/104909913/results",
    "logs_resource":"commands/104909913/logs"
  },
  "uid":5164,
  "perms":null,
  "command":{
    "query":"select * from abc ",
    "sample":false,
    "approx_mode":false,
    "approx_aggregations":false,
    "loader_table_name":null,
    "loader_stable":null,
    "md_cmd":false,
    "script_location":null
  },
  "instance":null
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `/tmp/2017-10-31/5031/104909913.dir/000` is only a key name. Are you sure you want to get only key names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more programmatic approach (that is, the jq program does not mention the "QBOL-QUERY-SCHEMA" key explicitly).  Whether this meets your actual needs, however, is unclear.

```
"id:\(.id)," + 
  (.qlog | fromjson | to_entries[0] | .key + ":" +
            (.value | to_entries[0] | .key) )
```

When jq is invoked with the -r option, this yields:

```
 id:104909913,QBOL-QUERY-SCHEMA:/tmp/2017-10-31/5031/104909913.dir/000
```

Answer (score 0):

`glog` property within your input object contains JSON text representation, in "*unparsed*" form.

To parse JSON text representation into values use `fromjson` function:

```
jq -r '"id:\(.id),QBOL-QUERY-SCHEMA:\(.qlog | fromjson | .["QBOL-QUERY-SCHEMA"] | keys[0])"' input.json
```

The output:

```
id:104909913,QBOL-QUERY-SCHEMA:/tmp/2017-10-31/5031/104909913.dir/000
```

Comment: awesome, that's what exactly I was looking for and it's pretty simple to say thanks for all your helps.